# How does -5 >> 2 === -2?

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

In the MDN docs, there is this example below under right shift operator.

```
const a = 5;          //  00000000000000000000000000000101
const b = 2;          //  00000000000000000000000000000010
const c = -5;         // -00000000000000000000000000000101

console.log(a >> b);  //  00000000000000000000000000000001
// expected output: 1

console.log(c >> b);  // -00000000000000000000000000000010
// expected output: -2
```

`5 >> 2` makes sense because you shift the digits right 2 spaces. In the second example of `-5 >> 2`, why does it only seemingly shift to the right one space even though it's `>> 2`?

MDN Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Right_shift

Comment: `5` in bin is `101` and `-5` is `11111111111111111111111111111011`. See [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Answer (score 2):

Just like Johnny side, you might want to check the Two's complement rule. The number in left most might be `1` inside of `0`. You might want to check the example with `-9` this example will help you understand better.